# categorical feature setting error in PMML GBDTLRClassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, lightgbm, pmml

I try to set up my GBDTLRClassifier following the instruction [here](https://openscoring.io/blog/2019/04/07/converting_sklearn_lightgbm_pipeline_pmml/).
First, I have done label encode on my columns. Then I define my categorical and continuous features, putting column names in two list.

```py
cat  # categorical column names
conts # continuous column names

gbm = lgb.LGBMClassifier(n_estimator = 90)
classifier = GBDTLRClassifier(gbm, LogisticRegression(penalty='l2'))
dm = DataFrameMapper([([cat_col], CategoricalDomain()) for cat_col in cat] + [(conts, ContinuousDomain())])

pipeline = PMMLPipeline([('mapper', dm), ('classifier', classifier)])
pipeline.fit(df[cat + conts], df['y'], classifier__gbdt__eval_set=[(val[cat + conts], val['y'])], classifier__gbdt__early_stopping_rounds = 5, classifier__gbdt__categorical_feature=cat)

pp = make_pmml_pipeline(pipelin, target_fields=['y'])
sklearn2pmml(pp, '/tmp/lgb+lr.pmml')
```

I get error message in fitting:`TypeError: Wrong type(str) or unknown name(root) in categorical_feature`. While `root` is definitely in `cat`. Looks like lgbm not aware of which columns are categorical, which is confusing.

Moreover, when I remove the mapper part, no fitting error but convert failed in making pmml file with message: `transformer object of the first step does not specify the number of input features`.

Does anyone could tell how to make this procedure work. THx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on comment [here](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/8f7199a44b290a13e8b4a82eb45f7389785c26fe/python-package/lightgbm/sklearn.py#L431), need to set `feature_name` when I send string column names into `categorical_feature`. A little tricky here.